# Exclude Library folder from being searched with find command in Terminal–OS X Mavericks

Tags: shell, applescript, find-util

I'm trying to make an AppleScript that searches for a specific folder called *keyPRO* inside the user's home folder. I'm using the following code in my AppleScript to do this:

```
do shell script "find ~/ -name 'keyPRO'"
```

(The "~/" means search inside the current user's home folder.)

What's annoying is that every time I run it, Terminal searches inside my Library folder which causes a "Permission denied" error, as well as other random stuff showing up.

Is there a way to exclude the user's Library folder from being searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally tagging your question with [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) or, more specficially, [find-util](/questions/tagged/find-util) would have gotten it more attention ([terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) doesn't come into play here - AppleScript's `do shell script` doesn't open a terminal window, it merely creates a *shell* child process.).

```
do shell script "find ~ -path ~/Library -prune -o -name 'keyPRO' -print"
```

will exclude `~/Library` from your find command.

From a shell, run `man find` for more information on the `find` command.

However, note that you wouldn't ordinarily see warnings or error messages when you use AppleScript's `do shell script`, unless the shell command *fails* (reports a nonzero exit code) as a whole (in which case AppleScript throws an error with the shell error message as the description).

Warnings and error message are sent to the *stderr* stream, whereas `do shell script` by default only captures *stdout*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! A bit long for my liking but this will do. This was my first question so I hope you'll forgive me for being a nooby tagger.

Comment: @TheWiseTurtle: My pleasures; glad to hear it. No worries re tagging; we all were noobs once.